# Read json file in nested folders

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, file

I have director structure like this, only `$(Root Directory)`'s name  is known at run time.

other folders and files are generated dynamically.(All files are `.json`)

my requirement is I need to count no of files and read content of all files using jquery and ajax.

I know if we have some static path like `abc/xyz/somefile.json` then we can read `someFile.json` but in my case I need to traverse nested folders.

help

[image]

Comment: Simply you cant . JavaScript cannot search for folders or file

Comment: Not realy agree with that...
if you have the rights to do XHR requests and you know the naming convention for folders and files... 

Assuming : 
`$(Root Directory) = "http://foo.bar/mylib"`
directory namming pattern are `folder_[0-9]+`
and files namming pattern are `file_[0-9]+.json`

You can write a small-crawler that iterates on all folders/files and interupt loop on 404 errors ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to do it without server-side support, either from the web server itself or another server-side process.

If directory listing is enabled on your web server, you can make an ajax request directly to the directory you want and scrape the returned document's content.

Another way would be to setup a web service which allows to query a directory's content. That service would be responsible for querying the file system and return the information to the client in a data-interchange format like JSON.